# Roots of $P_n(z)=1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^n$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

So I know that the factorization of $z^n-1$ is:
$$z^{n}-1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(z-e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{n}k)})$$
But I don't see how to factorize the monic polynomial $1+z+...+z^n$, where none of the coefficients is null.

Comment: It's all the roots of unity that are not equal to $1.$ Do you know the sum of a geometric series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $$\displaystyle{z^{n+1}-1=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}(z-e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{n+1}k)})}$$ and $$\displaystyle{z^{n+1} -1 = (z-1)(1+\cdots+z^n)}$$ we get that :
$$\displaystyle{(1+\cdots+z^n) = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(z-e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{n+1}k)}\right)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$P_n(z)=\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that : $$ P_{n}\left(z\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{z^{k}}=\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left(z-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{2k\pi}{n+1}}\right)} $$